# Visual Studio 2015 Community will not install from .exe file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am running windows 10 and I really need visual studio community to start working on learning C#.  I have used visual studio in the past for Visual Basic.  I downloaded the .exe file from Microsoft's website and when I click on the .exe file to run it I get a quick downloading files pop-up and then the visual studio logo appears briefly in the middle of the screen and then disappears.  I have tried restarting the computer and downloading the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.  Nothing seems to be working.  If anyone could lend me a hand in this endeavor that would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try the ISO download and run a local setup. Granted, it's a big download, but the full setup is more robust than the web installer sometimes.

Comment: @dxiv That didn't work either.  Not sure what's going on.  When I burnt it to a usb and clicked on the install and as administrator it will not run.  It does the same thing the .exe file did.  Visual Studio flashes on the screen for a second, then disappears.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any magic idea. Maybe post the setup logs to the respective MS forum, as directed at the end of [Common issues in Visual Studio 2015 setup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361) under `More Information`.